# I am having problem assigning values inside jwt.sign( )

Tags: node.js, jwt

I was trying to sign my payload with `jwt.sign()` method. I chose the async way (that you can pass a callback function as parameter), and it looked like this:

```js
jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secret', (err, token) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(token) // Token logs here successfully
})
```

Then I tried to declare a variable outside the function, and tried to assign the value of token to it, so I could use it later for sending it to client (to store it in a localstorage).

This is what I did next:

```js
let signedToken

jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secret', (err, token) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(token) // Token logs here successfully
  signedToken = token 
  console.log(signedToken) // signedToken logs successfully
})

console.log(signedToken) // logs 'Undefined'
```

So the value shows undefined outside the scope of function. I don't know if I'm missing very basic stuffs?

Comment: you need to wrap the callback with promise... and then await the whole promise...

Comment: this is the whole point of async, the event fires, but didnt finish and is keep runbing the rest of the code.. and then adter the rest of the code finished, the callback is executed...

Comment: thank you for response! should i do `async (err, token) => {  }` ?

Comment: wont make any changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(signedToken)` is called before jwt.sign (async) is completed.

you need to use

```
let signedToken = jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secret')
console.log(signedToken)
```

If you really want to do it the async way with async/await you need to wrap it with a promise.

```
    let signedToken = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jwt.sign(payLoad, 'secret', (err, token) => {
          if (err) reject(err)
           //...do what u want with the token
          resolve(token)
       })
    })
```

Comment: Hi, thank you :) but what if, i want to pass a callback into `jwt.sign()` ?

Comment: added a promise solution, but it's additional pointless step. callback is only useful if jwt.sign is going to be the last step in ur function.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I also have another question, if you are willing to answer! why it is only going to be useful if its the last step in my function?

Comment: From your code you do notice `console.log(signedToken)` is not getting the value from `jwt.sign`'s callback function. If you can't get the token, I don't think there's anything you can do after. So what we will usually do is to put `res.json({token})`, **INSIDE** the callback, not outside. That's what I meant by last step.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!